# How to create text animation with typewritter effects using anime js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, anime.js

Hi I am trying to create different animation with [anime js](https://animejs.com/), now I would like to create text animation with Typewriter Effect using anime.js, like this one here [demo live](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/).

Here is what I have so far.

HTML:

```
<div class="text-animation">
  Welcome to codingflag
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin:0px;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  background:#222;
}
.text-animation {
  color:#f5f5f5;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:"Passion One",sans-serif;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}
.text-animation .letter {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is js.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("text-animation")[0];
element.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(/\S/g,'<span class="letter">$&</span>');
anime.timeline({loop:true})
.add({
  targets:'.text-animation .letter',
  scale:[3,1],
  opacity:[0,1],
  translateZ:0,
  duration:1000,
  easing:"easeOutExpo",
  delay:(elem, index) => index*70
})
.add({
  targets:'.text-animation',
  opacity:0,
  duration:1000,
  delay:1000,
  easing:"easeOutExpo"
})
```

**Here is my CODPEN:** [type writer effect](https://codepen.io/dsr/pen/MWwMMXp).

What do I need to add to get the result I want as per the sample I have provided above.?

Comment: So do you mean that you don't want the zoom-in and you also require a cursor? Is that right?

Comment: hej I just want something like this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/ but in anime.js

Comment: You can try modifying this: https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hardest part of this typing animation is offset calculation for cursor which can be easily done by using combination of [HTMLElement.offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) and [HTMLElement.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) for each letter of the word.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.text-animation');
  const lettersHtml = element.textContent.replace(/\S/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>');
  element.innerHTML = `<div class="letters">${lettersHtml}</div><span class="cursor"></span>`;
  element.style.display = 'block';

  const letters = Array.from(element.querySelectorAll('.letter'));
  const TYPE_AFTER_MS = 3_000;
  const JUMP_AFTER_MS = 250;

  const blink = anime({
    targets: '.text-animation .cursor',
    loop: true,
    duration: 750,
    opacity: [
      {value: [1, 1]},
      {value: [0, 0]}
    ],
  });

  anime.timeline({loop: true})
    .add({
      targets: '.text-animation .cursor',
      translateX: letters.map((letter, i) =>
        ({value: letter.offsetLeft + letter.offsetWidth, duration: 1, delay: i === 0 ? 0 : JUMP_AFTER_MS}))
    }, TYPE_AFTER_MS)
    .add({
      targets: '.text-animation .letter',
      opacity: [0, 1],
      duration: 1,
      delay: anime.stagger(JUMP_AFTER_MS),
      changeBegin: () => {
        blink.reset();
        blink.pause();
      },
      changeComplete: () => {
        blink.restart();
      }
    }, TYPE_AFTER_MS)
    .add({
      targets: '.text-animation',
      opacity: 0,
      duration: 1000,
      delay: 500,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
    });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}

.text-animation {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Passion One", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.text-animation .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-animation">
  Welcome to codingflag
</div>
```

Comment: thanks bro, works perfectly, is there any demo about text reveal animation in anime js? if yes can you provide one?  here is my thread about that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397632/how-to-create-text-reveal-animation-with-anime-js

Comment: Nice! I managed to make my cursor follow the letters using flex. I set the 'order' for the cursor to 2, and then animated each letters order from 3 to 1. So the cursor shifts to the right as each letter shows.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Typed.js](https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)..because it's very easy to use...Here is an example made with [Typed.js](http://mattboldt.github.io/typed.js/)...

And here is My example...

```js
var typed = new Typed('#text', {
    strings: ["First String..!","Second String..!","Third String..!","Third Word..!"],
    typeSpeed: 120,
    backSpeed: 80,
    loop: true
 });
```

```css
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #051937, #004d7a, #008793, #00bf72, #a8eb12);
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
h2{
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!--Typed.js CDN-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.5/typed.min.js"></script>

<!--Body-->
<div class="container">
  <h2 id="text"></h2>
</div>
```

---